# Можно ли граббер поставить автоматическое обновление?

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется скрипт граббера, всего грабит всего лишь одну цифру с сайта , толи то 1 то ли то 0 ... но когда в переменной очень много никнеймов, получается очень долгая обработка данных... 
Меня интересует каким образом можно сделать что б раз в 5 минут информация обновлялась сама, а при запросе страницы выдавался ответ уже обработанной информации некоторое время до .. )
Вот сам скрипт

```
     <?php
function getPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12');
    $data_fin = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data_fin;
}
$ups = "&noredir=9462fa1c293699b04eb15e8b8d84b9ba";
$nick_names = ['FC SD']; // пример произвольного массива ник-неймов
$length = count($nick_names);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {

    $url = "http://w2.dwar.ru/user_info.php?nick=" . urlencode($nick_names[$i]) . $ups;
    $page = getPage($url);
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $pos = strpos($content, '&lvl=');
     $content = substr($content, $pos);
     $pos = strpos($content, '&tSrc=images');
     $content = substr($content, 0, $pos);
     $content = str_replace('&lvl=','', $content);
    $icon = "<a href='http://w2.dwar.ru/clan_info.php?clan_id=1070' title='TRIAS Dius'><img src='http://w2.dwar.ru/images/data/clans/3212331.gif' border=0 width=13 height=13 align='absmiddle'></a>";
 if (preg_match('/online=1/',$page)) {

         echo '<button class="btn-clipboard" data-clipboard-text="prv[' . $nick_names[$i] . ']"><img src="http://www.dwar.ru/images/news-arrow.gif"></button> ' . $nick_names[$i] . ' [' . $content . ']<a href="' . $url . '" target="_blank"><img src="http://w2.dwar.ru/images/player_info.gif" border=0 width=10 height=10 align="absmiddle"></a> : <span style="color: green;"><b>Online</b></span><br><br>';
    } else {
        echo '<button class="btn-clipboard" data-clipboard-text="prv[' . $nick_names[$i] . ']"><img src="http://www.dwar.ru/images/news-arrow.gif"></button> ' . $nick_names[$i] . ' [' . $content . ']<a href="' . $url . '" target="_blank"><img src="http://w2.dwar.ru/images/player_info.gif" border=0 width=10 height=10 align="absmiddle"></a> : <span style="color: red;"><b>Offline</b></span><br><br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно разбить задачу на две. Первая задача запускается cron раз в несколько минут (подбирается экспериментально) и грабит данные по каждому пользователю. Результаты награбленного складывает в базу.

Второй скрипт уже работает для пользователя. Когда ему нужно показать состояние, он прост идет в базу и выдает результат.

Comment: Я в принципе так и предполагал )) а нет у вас примера какого нибудь , который можно будет разобрать )) никогда не делал такого , а сайт грузит очень сильно ((

Comment: Что то нашел, попробую ночью поковырятся сам, если не получится, то задам новый вопрос, спасибо )